Modify lat and lng of a store
Can the lat and lng of a store be modified using the Geocoding API?
Through other APIs, I can't achieve what I need.
From what I saw in the documentation, this is not possible with this API, but I'm asking just in case there might be any possibility

The API to modify a store's location would be the Business Profile APIs (fka Google My Business API).
It only allows modifying stores you own / admin. If that would help you, contact Support to request access.
Neither the Geocoding API nor any other one of the Google Maps Platform APIs support modifying stores.
